# Existence of a Rectifiable Piecewise Smooth Path

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, plane-curves

Suppose you have $\gamma(t):[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ simple piecewise smooth, $\gamma(0) = 0$ and $\gamma(1)=1$.  Does there exist $\eta:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, another simple piecewise smooth curve, with $\eta(0) = 0$ and $\eta(1)$ a point on the unit circle, such that $\gamma$ and $\eta$ only intersect at the origin?

My attempt: I tried approaching this constructively, but I couldn't seem to get my hands on anything useful.  The best alternative I could come up with was trying to use the Riemann mapping theorem to find a conformal map $f: \mathbb{D}\setminus\gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$.  If $f$ extends continuously to the boundary, then I could use a chord $A$ which joins $f(0)$ to $f(-1)$, and then let $\eta = f^{-1}(A)$.  But, even then, I'm not sure if I can guarantee that the resulting $\eta$ has nonzero one-sided derivatives at the endpoints.  So my strategy only works in nice situations (as far as I know).

Is there a general topological approach to this?  Can my Riemann mapping strategy be made to work, or is it hopeless?

Comment: (Nitpick: $\gamma$ has to be injective.)

Comment: Judging by your attempt, you want $\eta(1)$ to be a point on the unit circle, not "on the unit disk". Is that right?

Comment: Ah, right.  Sorry!  Also corrected.

Comment: This is just an idea: It seems intuitively that the path's benign properties should guarantee that you can define a path at distance $\epsilon$ "to the left" of $\gamma$, and that the infimum of $\epsilon$ such that this path intersects $\gamma$ should be non-zero. If so, it seems it should be possible to hook such a path up to the origin and the unit circle for sufficiently small $\epsilon$?

Comment: @joriki I like that idea.  For some reason, though, I keep running into trouble with making it precise.  In particular, I can start by saying that there's some path that reaches from a point on the circle to an interior point that's $\epsilon$-close to the origin.  But then I run into a self-similar problem.  How do I know that I can hook up my $\epsilon$-close point, which lives on the circle of radius $\epsilon$, to the origin without crossing $\gamma$?  So I keep landing back at square one.

Comment: What is the definition of piecewise smooth that you use? Does it include $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ everywhere (where in the points where $\gamma$ is not differentiable both one-sided derivatives shall be nonzero)? [Apart from that, piecewise smooth implies rectifiable in the definitions I'm aware of, the problem in your approach is whether $\eta$ has a one-sided derivative at $0$ and at $1$.]

Comment: "How do I know that I can hook up my $\epsilon$-close point, which lives on the circle of radius $\epsilon$, to the origin without crossing $\gamma$?" Because the line from the origin to that point is the line of initial points of paths left-shifted by less than $\epsilon$ -- if it crosses $\gamma$, then one of those paths crosses $\gamma$, which can't be since we took the infimum.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've been omitting the assumption that one-sided derivatives exist everywhere, but I think I'll edit the question to reflect the more standard definition that you stated.

Now that I've got my definitions right, it sounds like there are two problems with my approach: 1.) I can't guarantee that my conformal map extends continuously to the boundary (this seems reasonable, but there could be some obstruction I'm unaware of) and 2.) as you noted, I can't guarantee one-sided derivatives for $\eta$

Comment: @joriki I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but is your left shift just translation of $\gamma$?  If so, I can't see why our infimum should be nonzero.

Comment: Also, thanks to you both for sticking around.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @JoshKeneda: No, sorry, I wrote "left-shifted" as a shorthand in that last comment, I meant a path at distance $\epsilon$ "to the left" of $\gamma$, as I'd written originally -- i.e. not translated by a constant in a fixed direction, but everywhere at (normal) distance $\epsilon$ from $\gamma$ -- a [parallel or offset curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve).

Comment: @joriki Ah.  I haven't met those before, so I'll read up and see if I can complete your argument.  Thanks for your help!